# C++ lazy singleton hangs on loading

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

I have lazy singleton class, that needs to be serialized using boost on the first call.

Header file:

```
class Singleton
{
public:

    static Singleton& Instance()
    {
        static Singleton theSingleInstance;
        return theSingleInstance;
    }

    void load();
private:
    Singleton();
    Singleton(const Singleton& root);
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);
    std::map<std::string,std::string > m_desc;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& arc, const unsigned int version)
    {
        arc & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_desc);
    }
    const char* FILENAME = "./config.xml";
};
```

Source file

```
#include "singleton.h"
Singleton::Singleton()
{
    load();
}


void Singleton::load()
{
    try
    {
        std::ifstream f(FILENAME);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive arc(f);
        arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Config",Instance());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So when I try to start my code using this singleton, it hangs. With the debugger I can see that it does not go to `load()` method many times (and it's ok). When I pause the debugger, it stops on the line `return theSingleInstance;`, but it does not go through the breakpoint on this line many times also. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call load from inside the constructor. Which means that you're *in the constructor* of your static `theSingleInstance` when you... call `Instance`
:

```
  #0   in Singleton::load at test.cpp <test.cpp>
  #1   in Singleton::Singleton at test.cpp <test.cpp>
  #2   in Singleton::Instance at test.cpp <test.cpp>
  #3   in main at test.cpp <test.cpp>
```

Since construction c++11 function-local statics is guaranteed to be thread safe, which means - in your implementation - that execution will block until the instance is fully constructed (or construction failed, so it can be retried).

Of course, that will never happen because construction is waiting for itself.

```
   0x00000000004030f5 <+629>:   callq  0x402be0 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>
=> 0x00000000004030fa <+634>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x00000000004030fc <+636>:   je     0x402ff1 <Singleton::load()+369>
```

Of course this is fixed by *not* using the external accessor while still constructing the instance, as you already found out.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the practice of giving singletons value-semantics - in case one day you don't want it to be a singleton any more and you want to avoid refactoring.

The other advantage is that it provides full encapsulation:

for example:

```
// config.h - extremely sparse interface
#include <string>

struct config
{
    /// Return a named value from the program's configuration
    /// @param name is the name of the required parameter
    /// @post the config file shall be cached
    /// @return the value if it exists
    /// @except std::invalid_argument if the value does not exist
    /// @except other exceptions if the config file does not load
    ///
    const std::string& value(const std::string& name) const;

private:
    struct impl;
    static impl& get();
};

// config.cpp - the implementation

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

struct config::impl
{
    impl()
    {
        std::ifstream f(FILENAME);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive arc(f);
        arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Config", *this);
    }

    std::map<std::string,std::string > m_desc;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& arc, const unsigned int version)
    {
        arc & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_desc);
    }

    static constexpr const char* FILENAME = "./config.xml";
};

config::impl& config::get() {
    static impl _;
    return _;
}

const std::string& config::value(const std::string& name) const
{
    return get().m_desc.at(name);
}

// demo.cpp

// note - config is copyable, and this has almost no cost
void do_something_with(config cfg)
{

}

struct no_config {};   // some other config source?

// now I can switch on config type at compile time - code can be
// more generic
void do_something_with(no_config)
{

}

int main()
{
    // single-use
    std::string my_value = config().value("foo");

    // pass my config source to a function        
    do_something_with(config());

    // a similar function that uses a different config source
    do_something_with(no_config());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: to replace this line

```
arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Config",Instance());
```

with

```
arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Config",*this);
```

Comment: You didn't explain why this makes a difference :)